# How to upgrade a Bazel-aware library's Maven dependency?

Tags: bazel

My library supports Bazel builds and has a dependency from Maven Central. A user of my library [wants to use a newer version of a dependency that has new transitive dependencies](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/5214). How can that be done?

gRPC 1.17 depends on Guava 26. However, Guava 27 added a dependency on `com.google.guava:failureaccess`. Normally an application using gRPC would just make their own `native.maven_jar()` with the new version and disable gRPC's call to `native.maven_jar()`. This would then "upgrade" the `@com_google_guava_guava` repository that is then consumed by both gRPC and the application.

But `@com_google_guava_guava` does not include dependency information. That is commonly solved by having third_party `java_library()`s that stitch the transitive dependencies together. However, those `java_library()`s can't be changed by the application.

I believe that [`bind()`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#bind) would solve this problem, as gRPC could depend on `//external:com_google_guava_guava` which could be a `java_library()`. But `bind()` is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update: [`rules_jvm_external`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external) is a new ruleset by the Bazel team to fetch and resolve artifacts transitively.

In this case, the WORKSPACE file will contain something like this:

```
load("@rules_jvm_external//:defs.bzl", "maven_install")

maven_install(
    artifacts = [
        "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre",
    ],
    repositories = [
        "https://jcenter.bintray.com",
    ]
)
```

This will automatically resolve and fetch the guava and failureaccess artifacts. Then in the BUILD file, you can directly depend on Guava like this:

```
java_library(
    name = "my_jar",
    srcs = # ...
    deps = [
        "@maven//com_google_guava_guava",
    ],
)
```

Comment: I saw the blog post, but it doesn't seem that simple. I see now that unlike normal rules `maven_install` has a default name. It seems you're suggesting for libraries to force their consumers to use that default `"maven"` name? I don't see how I can migrate to this, since I can't support the old and new targets at the same time; I'd have to abandon pre-existing users.

I do agree that the new rule is easier from an application perspective.

Comment: Here's an example rule library of how you can provide the `maven_install` with a special name, like `@maven_grpc_deps`, to downstream users: https://github.com/buchgr/rules_jmh#usage

Comment: If you wrap the `maven_install` call in `grpc_java_repositories()`, the change will be transparent to consumers.

Comment: Here's another example of moving from `java_import_external` to `maven_install`: https://github.com/higherkindness/rules_scala/pull/176/files

Comment: You can now generate the old `@group_artifact//jar` labels using `generate_compat_repositories`: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external/#repository-aliases

Comment: Jin, thank you so much. That means there is a migration story! I hadn't figured out how to swap gRPC to maven_install because of the lack of migration story for our users.

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching your library to use `java_import_external` instead of `maven_jar`.

`java_import_external` target [includes dependency information](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/java.bzl#L115-L118) and thus allow an application to supplant a target's version and its transitive dependencies.

Just remember to add `if native.existing_rule(name) == None:`
before you define `@com_google_guava_guava` in order to allow a user of your library to define it herself with the newer version of guava that has updated dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Having thought about this for a little while, I feel like `bind()` might be the best way for grpc-java to offer this. I'm not aware of any features in the existing Maven transition tools that would make this easier.

However, if the user wants to do it without changing grpc-java, they could:

1. In `WORKSPACE`, override `com_google_guava_guava` with a `local_repository()`:

   ```
   grpc_java_repositories(
       omit_com_google_guava = True,
   )

   maven_jar(
       name = "com_google_guava_guava_real",
       artifact = "com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre",
       sha1 = "bd41a290787b5301e63929676d792c507bbc00ae",
   )

   maven_jar(
       name = "com_google_guava_failureaccess",
       artifact = "com.google.guava:failureaccess:1.0.1",
       sha1 = "1dcf1de382a0bf95a3d8b0849546c88bac1292c9",
   )

   local_repository(
       name = "com_google_guava_guava",
       path = "guava_27",
   )
   ```
2. Create a subrepo that present a compatible `java_library()`:

   ```
   mkdir -p guava_27/jar
   echo > guava_27/WORKSPACE
   cat > guava_27/jar/BUILD.bazel << EOF
   java_library(
       name = "jar",
       visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
       exports = [
           "@com_google_guava_failureaccess//jar",
           "@com_google_guava_guava_real//jar",
       ],
   )
   EOF
   ```